# How to split a list

Tags: python, split

I have a textfile and the input is:

- abcdefg@hi
- jklmnop@qr

In the following I read every line into a list while stripping the `\n`:

```
with open(file) as f:
    return [email.strip() for email in f]
```

Output after printing the list: `[abcdefg@hi, jklmnop@qr]`

**BUT** I want to get only the part before the `@` like `abcdefg`. I need to use `split('@')` and then get `[0]`. But in which line in the with-open-code above I need to split it?

Another question: Does the expression `[email.strip() for email in f]` has any specific name?

Comment: There is no way you can end up with a list having values like `abcdefg:hi` based on the input you provided and the Python snippet given.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry I changed it now! My mistake :>

Comment: For your question about `[email.strip() for email in f]`, it's called `list comprehension`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `re.findall` here:

```py
with open(file) as f:
    data = f.read()
    emails = re.findall(r'(\S+)@\S+', data)
```

Comment: How about `r'(\S+)@'`?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, that would work with the exact data shown.  I am only trying to be more precise by matching a generic pattern for an email address.  Granted, my answer may have to change when the OP reveals its actual data to us.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open(file) as f:
   array = []
   for email in f:
       email = email.strip() 
       array.append(email.split('@')[0])
       
   return array
```

Comment: `email.split('@', 1)` or `email.partition('@')`